# Схема БД Oracle

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Объясните по простому, что такое схема БД *Oracle*?

Comment: Схема - это пространство имен для других объектов, таких как таблицы, пакеты, функции и т.п. имена объектов должны быть уникальны в пределах схемы.

Comment: Аа т.е все это вместе называется схема. Спасибо

Answer (score 5):

В БД *Oracle*, схема это коллекция логических структур данных, или объектов схемы, таких как: таблицы, индексы, пакеты, процедуры и т.д.
Схема принадлежит пользователю БД, создаётся автоматически при создании пользователя БД, и имеет тоже самое имя.

Для простоты понимания - фактически схема и пользователь БД это синонимы.

Технически - схема представляет из себя набор метаданных (data dictionary) используемый БД для построения связи между пользователем и физическими структурами данных.

Чтобы не путаться:

- В БД *Oracle* схема это не одно и тоже, что общее понятие схемы БД ([Database schema](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)).
- `CREATE SCHEMA ...` не создаёт никакой новой схемы, как в других СУБД. Этот   оператор создаёт объекты схемы в уже существующей схеме.

Подробнее: [у Тома](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6162110256950) и [в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/intro.htm#CNCPT940)